# Is there a 3D photo stitching app for Android? (as an alternative to Photosynth)

Tags: applications, photos

[Photosynth for iOS](http://itunes.apple.com/en/app/photosynth/id430065256?mt=8) is a great app that allows you to create 3D panoramas by taking multiple photos and automatically stitching them together.

Is there any alternative for Android?

I've already tried:

- [Camera360](https://market.android.com/details?id=vStudio.Android.Camera360&feature=search_result), despite the name, it doesn't create 3D panoramas
- [PhotAF](https://market.android.com/details?id=obg1.Photaf&feature=search_result), which only creates horizontal panoramas
- [360](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.vtcreator.android360&feature=also_installed_confirmation), only horizontal panoramas as well

Comment: A [simple search on the Market](https://market.android.com/search?q=photosynth&so=1&c=apps) gives at least a couple of likely candidates. Checking [AlternativeTo.net](http://alternativeto.net/software/photosynth/) reinforces at least one of them.